# Black border around sprite when moving it in LimeJS

Tags: limejs

Whenever I move a sprite using the following code, a black border will appear around it where there shouldn't be.

```
var navigate1 = new lime.animation.Sequence(
 new lime.animation.MoveTo(675,230).setDuration(1),
 new lime.animation.MoveTo(725,200).setDuration(1),
 new lime.animation.MoveTo(735,180).setDuration(1));
```

Is it something do with the code, or the sprite image?

Refreshing the screen in anyway (such as resizing the browser) would make the black borders disappear.

Comment: Like you said, it's a Chrome rendering bug

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure myself, but I believe what you need to do is create two rounded rectangles with a fill, make the inner one smaller than the outer one, then place the content inside of the inner rectangle, essentially layering the elements on top of each other.

Comment: It turns out that this is an issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I gotten this answer from (it should be a mailing list for LimeJS). This problem only occurs in LimeJS and seems to be related to the auto resizing of the scene. Putting the LimeJS scene into a  which has a height and width set solves the problem.